# (JFX) Troubles when loading images using a static method and inherited classes

Tags: image, javafx, imageview

I'm trying to load 2 images using a static method loadImage(String) that I made.
This method is stored in my Entity (abstract) class and my classes Projectile and Player are inheriting from this entity.

However when I'm using this method (2 times since i'm loading "Projectile.loadImage("image1");" and "Player.loadImage("image2");") only the second image is stored.

I'm thinking that it's cause by the inheritance since the loadImage() method is written in the Entity class so it might be changing the static sprite from the Entity and not Player or Projectile, but i don't know how to fix this without recreating a loadImage() method for all subclasses and having the subclasses not inheriting the sprite property but instead having their own ones

Here is an example of the code :

```
//Main class
package application;

import Entities.*;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Main extends Application
{
    final int WIDTH = 800;
    final int HEIGHT = 800;
    public int frameCount = 0;
    Player p;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Player.loadImage("/images/isaac.png");
        Projectile.loadImage("/images/tear.png");
        stage.setTitle("My first JFX / Java project");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        p = new Player(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2,root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

```
//Entity Class and load Image
package Entities;

import application.Vector2;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public abstract class Entity {
    protected double x;
    protected double y;
    private Group root;
    protected Vector2 dir;
    protected double speed;
    private static Image sprite;
    private ImageView iv;
    private int size;
    private double hp;
    public Entity(float px, float py,Group r, Image s) {
        root = r;
        x = px;
        y = py;
        size = 100;
        iv = new ImageView(s);
        dir = new Vector2(0,0);
        speed = 0.2;
        hp = 3;
        root.getChildren().add(iv);
        iv.setX(x);
        iv.setY(y);
        iv.setFitWidth(100);
        iv.setFitHeight(100);
    }
    public static void loadImage(String input) {
        sprite = new Image(input);
    }
```

```
//Player class constructor 
package Entities;

import application.Vector2;
import javafx.scene.Group;
public class Player extends Entity{


    private boolean north, west, south, east;
    private boolean shootN, shootW, shootS, shootE;
    private Vector2 pInput;

    public Player(float px, float py,Group r) {
        super(px,py,r,getSprite());
        north = false;
        west = false;
        south = false;
        east = false;
        pInput = new Vector2(0,0);
        setHp(10);
    }
}
```

```
//Projectile Constructor 
package Entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import application.Vector2;
import javafx.scene.Group;

public class Projectile extends Entity{
    private double speed;
    Entity parent;
    int lifespan;
    public Projectile(float px, float py,Group r,Entity p,Vector2 d){
        super(px,py,r,getSprite());
        speed = 5;
        dir = new Vector2(d.x,d.y);
        dir.x += p.dir.x/30;
        dir.y += p.dir.y/30;
        lifespan = 100;
        parent = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is expected behaviour: static fields are _shared_ across instances, so the second call resets the value of the first call. Moral of the story: don't use static access :)

Comment: So is there a way to load my projectile and player texture without using a static access ? Because when it comes to projectiles it seems a bit power-consuming to charge a texture everytime one is created
The way i solved this is by having each class have their own Image (so not inherited) and loadImage method and Image class but it seems a bit redundant

Comment: Of course the `Image` objects can be shared, just not the way you've implemented it in your question... The quick and dirty approach would be adding one `static Image` field per concrete class (and replacing the `getSprite` method with something that accesses these fields). A more clean approach would probably use a factory to create the objects and store the `Image` objects...